# diarization using speech_recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition

Is there a way to do speaker `diarization` using a free service/library?

I am using `speech_recognition` library to transcribe an audio file, and I want to identify the different speakers in the audio. I know that **Google Cloud** has a function called `enableSpeakerDiarization` which allow me to do this, but I don't want to use it (because is not free). I am looking for a free or open source solution.